# Lumen is giving Blank Page with 500 Internal Error on Post

Tags: laravel, debugging, nginx, digital-ocean, lumen

I have set the Lumen working. The debugging when hitting on a wrong route it gives a proper Laravel error log. However, when I try it with a Post route and it gives an 500 Internal Error, the page in network is blank. Chrome says `This request has no response data available`

My .env is

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=SomeRandomKey!!!
```

I am not sure if it's related with the host but I am using nginx with Digital Ocean.

---

I tried adding this in public/index.php, but no luck..

```
try {
    $app->run();
} catch(\Exception $e) {
    echo "<pre>";
    echo $e;
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

---

What may be the problem

**Edit:** The function I am trying to call:

```
public function index(Request $request) {
        $a = $request->all();

        foo($a)
}

private function foo($a) {
      print($a)
}
```

Comment: Don't you have some kind of error in your nginx error logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $a = $request->all();

    $this->foo($a);
}

private function foo($a)
{
    print_r($a);
}
```